# alternative to javascript: when colon is filtered

Tags: javascript, xss

I setup a purposely vulnerable form on my website to test some xss vectors.
Then i thought with href xss, if : is filtered then how would xss be possible because you'd have to insert `javascript:alert(1)` like this `<a href="javascript:alert(1)"`? say %3A isn't allowed either.
Thanks to anyone who can help me on this.

Comment: if you filtered ":", you won't be able to have any external links...

Comment: Please clarify your question to at least include the extra information that you posted in the comments on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question literally, if only `<`, `>`, `:`, `%` and quotes are filtered then you can still do

```
javascript&#58;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zaN9m/

Please don't take this as a hint to just add this extra character. This is exactly the game where you are always
one step behind. And you will not be able to allow harmless input if you do the "filter all bad chars out" thing, so yeah.

Consider what happens when you start looking out for `&#58;` and I pass `javascript:&:#:5:8:;`. The filter will not detect `&#58;` there
but will remove the colons and the result will be `javascript&#58;` after colons are filtered out and it's again a checkmate.

What you want to do is to see if the URL has a scheme and match it against known good schemes like http and https. You will then also have
to apply HTML encoding to the result. This is bullet proof and you don't have to play games.